# I need to combine two tables and then joiing with 10 more tables in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have select SQL query in `vb.net` as below to fetch record. Except for `table1` & `table1history` all other conditions are seems to be same. Is there any way to place the filtered date from `table1` & `table2` into a `temp` table and perfom multiple join only once against the `temp` ?

```
select 
    colA, colB, ... 
from 
    table1 
join 
    table2 on tabel1.col = table2.col
join 
    table3 on tabel3.col = table2.col
join 
    table4 on tabel4.col = table2.col
join 
    table5 on tabel5.col = table2.col
join 
    table6 on tabel6.col = table5.col
left join 
    table7 on tabel7.col = table5.col
Left join 
    table8 on tabel8.col = table4.col
Left join 
    table9 on tabel9.col = table8.col
Left join 
    table10 on tabel10.col = table5.col

union

select 
    colA, colB, ... 
from 
    table1History 
join 
    table2 on tabel1History.col = table2.col
join 
    table3 on tabel3.col = table2.col
join 
    table4 on tabel4.col = table2.col
join 
    table5 on tabel5.col = table2.col
join 
    table6 on tabel6.col = table5.col
left join 
    table7 on tabel7.col = table5.col
Left join 
    table8 on tabel8.col = table4.col
Left join 
    table9 on tabel9.col = table8.col
Left join 
    table10 on tabel10.col = table5.col;
```

Comment: You need to loose the unnecessary **comma** (`,`) at the end of every single join condition !

Comment: I added those unknowingly while typing here.

Comment: Hi @newbie - are you sure that's not what's going on anyway - have you got some sort of performance explanation??

Comment: The existing select query i like above whether they are performing joins with multiple tables and union with the exact same tables except for one history table. So is there a way to join table1 and table1history and apply filters and then do multiple joins? the above query is working but it takes time to execute.